# Query optimization to avoid matching on a column with only a few distinct values

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in sql-server.

```
System{
  AUTO_ID           -- identity auto increment primary key
  SYSTEM_GUID       -- index created, unique key
}

File{
  AUTO_ID       -- identity auto increment primary key
  File_path
  System_Guid -- foreign key refers system.System_guid, index is created
              -- on this column
}
```

System table has 100,000 rows.
File table has 200,000 rows.
File table has only 10 distinct values for `System_guid`.

My Query is as follows:

```
Select * from 
File left outer join System
on file.system_guid = system.system_guid
```

SQL server is using hash match join to give me result which is taking a long time.

I want to optimize this query to make it go faster.  The fact that there are only 10 distinct system_guid probably means the hash match wastes energy.  How can utilize this knowledge to speed up the query?

Comment: Do you have any filtering criteria? Or are you selecting all rows from the tables?

Comment: @astander In this query I need to display all results. No filtering.

Comment: If there are only 10 distinct `system_guid` values, then your query could easily be generating about 2 billion rows. How fast do you think that should run? I'm pretty sure that's your performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

When an indexed column has almost non-changing values, the purpose of index fails. If all you want is to extract records from System where system_guid is one of the ones in File then you may be better off (in your case) with a query like:

```
select * from System 
where system_guid in (select distinct system_guid from File).
```

Comment: I need to print output as SystemName, FileName .... and that to using left outer join. So your suggestion doesn't work.

Comment: You said that System has 100K rows, right? And system_guid is unique, right? How then, there are only 10 or so distinct system_guid's? Please update the problem description.

Comment: I said File table has only 10 distinct system_guid values. So my description is correct

Answer (score 0):

Is the LEFT join really necessary? How does the query perform as an INNER join? Do you get a different join.

I doubt hash join is much of a problem with this amount of I/O.

You could do a UNION like this... maybe coax a different plan out of it.

```
Select * from File 
WHERE System_Guid NOT IN (SELECT system_guid from system)
union all
Select * from 
File inner join System
on file.system_guid = system.system_guid
```